# Mongodb query on field value if included in long string

Tags: string, mongodb, include, find

Given `stringX = "term|quote|text"`. I want to do a query on mongodb of the following documents:

```
[{
 id:"1",
 description:"term"
},
{
 id:"2",
 description:"term2"
},
{
 id:"3",
 description:"term3"
}]
```

How do I find the document with `id:1`? The pseudo query is the like of:

```
"find document, which description is included (to be found) in stringX".
```

Comment: The only solution looks is to have an `$or` of each search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query expression with the [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator from the string. Your ultimate query object should resemble:

```
var query = {
    "description": { "$in": ["term", "quote", "text"] }
}
```

Or if you prefer using [**`$or`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

```
var query = {
    "$or": [
        { "description": "term" },
        { "description": "quote" },
        { "description": "text" }
    ]
}
```

which you can then use in your query asin

```
db.collection.find(query)
```

To get the query in the first form, **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** the input string with the pipe as the delimiter and use the resulting array as the [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator's value:

```
var query = {
    "description": { "$in": stringX.split("|") }
};
db.collection.find(query)
```

For the second form, consider using the **[`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method on the split string, something like the following

```
var orOperator = stringX.split("|").map(function (str){ return { "description": str } }),
    query = { "$or": orOperator };
db.collection.find(query)
```

Comment: Thank chridam! I tried the solution 1 and it worked! Nice solution.